# Dynamically update progressbar yiiframework

Tags: php, yii

He there!

I have function that calculates a percentage, these percentage is based on time. There is a start time ( for example 15:00) and an endtime (for example 15:05). If I call this function on 15:02, the outcome would be 40%.

```
public function getBuildPercentage() {
    $currentTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); //50
    $boughtTime = strtotime($this->boughtTime); 
    $finishTime = strtotime($this->finishTime); //100

    $first = $currentTime - $boughtTime; 
    $second = $finishTime - $boughtTime; 

    $percentage =   round(($first / $second) * 100);    

    // if the percentage is higher than 100 -> item is finished
    if($percentage >= 100)
        $this->setToFinished($this->id); 

    return $percentage; 
}
```

I display this percentage using the bootstrap progressbar widget as following:

```
<?php
    $this->widget(
        'bootstrap.widgets.TbProgress',
        array(
            'type' => 'success', 
            'percent' => $item->getBuildPercentage(),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                'title' => 'Approximately ...to go.'
                )                                
            )
        )
?>
```

Currently, the user has to refresh the page to see the exact value of the percentage and the correct progress bar.

It would be really cool if the progressbar would update dynamically (so without refreshing).

What would be the best way to this? Ajax? (I don't have any experience with that, so if you could also give an example, that would be really great!)

Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for AJAX you should have access to your function via request, so place this code in your controller:

```
public function actionPercentage($id) {
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
   $item = YourModelName::model()->findByPk($id); //obtain instance of object containing your function
   echo $item->getBuildPercentage(); //to return value in ajax, simply echo it   
}
}
```

Then, in your view you can register script that each second will send request to server to get current percentage:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('ajax-percentage','
   var interval = 1000;
   setInterval(function() { $.ajax(
        type: "GET",
        url: '.Yii::app()->createUrl('yourController/percentage', array('id'=>$item->id)).',
        success: function (percents) {
            // you have got your percents, so you can now assign it to progressbar value here
        }
 )}, interval);
');
```

I also suggest you to use [JQuery UI Progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label) if you have any problems with Bootstrap widget.